# Retrieving images from the database and injecting them into listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, image, listview

I have a table BIKETYPE { BIKETYPEID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, IMAGE}.

IMAGE has a datatype of `image`. I am trying to display the table through list view. I am able to see everything except the image column.

My code is as follow

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BikeTypeId") %></td>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %></td>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Description") %></td>
        <td><asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# "Handler.ashx?BikeTypeId="+ Eval("image") %>' ID="Image" runat="server" /></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="Select" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" /></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

In the code behind, I am using simple bind method as follow

```
protected void bind()
{
        adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From BikeType", str);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        ListView1.DataSource = ds;
        ListView1.DataBind();
        ds.Clear();
        adp.Dispose();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this [article](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/414/storing-uploaded-files-in-a-database-or-in-the-file-system-with-aspnet-20) and [this](http://odetocode.com/articles/172.aspx).. It will exactly explain with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the images can be displayed into listview or any other control by using Genric Handler.
Add A Genric Handler By Adding new Item > Genric Handlers and then Refer to the Code Below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
namespace letsride
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Handler1
    /// </summary>
    public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["b_id"]);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bikewebConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select image from Biketype where BikeTypeId=@id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);

            object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            try
            {
                context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])img);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Response.Write(ex.Message);



            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in your Web Forms use image as

```
<asp:Image ID="i" runat="server"   ImageUrl='<%# "Handler.ashx?b_id=" + Eval("BikeTypeId") %> ' /></td>
```

BikeTypeID is the ID of table in database
also refer to http://makhaai.blogspot.com.au/2010/11/image-handling-in-aspnet-part-1.html

Comment: +1, I just learned two things from this : How to use a handler and how to retrieve an image from database and use it. Thanks